# reminder system in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to create a small reminder system in PHP over the weekend. The plan is

1. Users sign up.
2. Users create reminders and todos using a simple form, inputting details such as reminder name, description and time. This information is stored in a MySQL database.
3. Script checks the database for reminders that are due to be sent and sends them to the users email and perhaps other actions.

Whats the best way of approaching the script that checks/sends or can someone suggest another idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would run a cronjob on your server that would run every x minutes. Each time it runs it would check the database for reminders at the current time and then e-mail the user who made the reminder.

Comment: It is recommended you also build a queue system into this implementation so you only send 100 or so a minute to prevent serious problems should your user base grow to a large size. So your cron would check for notifications and add them to a queue table. Then that same cron can also check the queue system and grab the next 100 in queue to send and fire them away.

Comment: So, if I added LIMIT 100 to the end of my SQL statement, would this work like a queue system or limiting system?

Comment: That would act as a limiting system. I'm assuming you mean LIMIT 100 users to send e-mails too. If this is the case then users who are #101+ will never get an e-mail. Instead you need to add ALL users to a queue (i.e, another table). The cron job then has two tasks: add all users to the queue, and then message the 100 oldest users in the queue their reminder. Then delete those 100 from the queue.

Comment: Technically you can, but you would use a queue system for scalability unless that is not a concern of yours. Consider what happens if your user notification system has millions of rows to evaluate. You might limit that evaluation alone and your queue system as a stand alone cron job can still be chugging away regardless of the actions of the notification system. It's your call really - you know your system and I'm just relaying how we set up this kind of thing at our firm.

Answer (score 0):

If you server supports cron jobs use them.

1. Create your php script which checks and then send email to corresponding user.
2. Create a cron job to run that script with a syntax like this one:

   php -q /home/serverpath/script/file.php

CPanel does have a section for cronjobs