# Setup reminder system with cron

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cron, daemon

I have specific dates for users interviews. Here is my table:

```
interviews
-------------
user_id
interview_date
interview_time
reminder_time
```

The reminder time can be 1 hour, 5 hours, 1 day, 3 days, 7 days, and 14 days.

How would I go about setting up a cron job or something to check the database and send out a reminder if the interview is coming up?

For example, if the interview is 5 hours away, the database would send an email reminder to that user.

Should I use cron? Daemon? Not familair with daemon, just saw it when I was searching it up. Or should I use something else? This is a pure/native PHP application with no frameworks.

Here is what i have so far:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM interviews");

if(interview is coming up) {
    sendEmail();
}
```

but i'm confused as to where and how should I search for these interviews and send out reminders.

If i search for ALL interviews, that is putting a huge load on the server.

thank you for all the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want your PHP process to run perpetually you'll need some kind of regular scheduler like `cron`. This can set your code to run once every minute, every hour, or whatever interval makes sense.

Normally every five or fifteen minutes is sufficient to check for upcoming events and send out notifications for them.

Be sure to set a flag in your database for if something has been notified already so if your script crashes and you need to re-run it can pick up where it left off.

Comment: i've been doing a lot of research, would RabbitMQ be suitable for this?

Comment: RabbitMQ is a great message-bus but it generally runs jobs once and once only. There's no mechanism for repeating them unless they've failed, and then it retries immediately.

Comment: Great! i'm just trying to wrap my head around this, how would i use RabbitMQ to search the database? Or would I have to search the database with cron, then send email reminders via RabbitMQ? If I go with the latter option, wouldn't using a cron suffice?

Comment: Think of RabbitMQ as a message bus. It's not a database. It's not a job scheduler.

Comment: `cron` is *just* a job scheduler. It runs commands, that's it. If those commands connect to a database, that's fine, but `cron` itself can't. RabbitMQ just delivers messages to programs. It can't replace `cron`. It can't connect to databases.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. i guess what i'm trying to get at is this: I will have a php script inside my cron that checks the database for upcoming invitations. How would RabbitMQ effectively play into this?

Comment: It wouldn't unless you have a reason to run a bunch of background jobs, e.g. sending out individual reminder emails.

Comment: Ahh I see, so using RabbitMQ is really only efficient if I need to send the actual reminders? But if the reminders don't take that long to send, it wouldn't make sense to use RabbitMQ? For example: `sendEmail()` vs `addJobIntoRabbitMQ` took the same amount of time, `sendEmail()` would be faster, since the latter would need to add a job for RabbitMQ, and then RabbitMQ needs to send the email. If that is the case, what is RabbitMQ even used for? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: By the way, this is the comment I was reading that made me think of a queue system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121310/reminder-system-in-php#comment11461995_9121338

Comment: Although RabbitMQ is really great at what it does, I think you're over-complicating what should be a simple solution here. Check times. Send emails. Wrap up. Repeat every five minutes. RabbitMQ may become relevant *at scale* when you're sending 10K+ emails per round.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much for the help! :)

Comment: If that solves your problem, mark it as an accepted answer. This helps others in the same situation.

Comment: Ahh yes, forgot about that!